# store Cloud SQL credentials securely and efficiently to use in Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to securely connect to a Cloud SQL (postgres) instance from my Cloud Function using Secrets Manager. However, I am confused as to

- what should be stored as a secret,
- whether multiple secrets should be stored separately, and
- how to access those secrets from Cloud Function

Given this sample code,

```py
    # Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
    # secure - consider a more secure solution such as
    # Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
    # keep secrets safe.

    instance_connection_name = os.environ[
        "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
    ]  # e.g. 'project:region:instance'
    db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]  # e.g. 'my-db-user'
    db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]  # e.g. 'my-db-password'
    db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]  # e.g. 'my-database'

    ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC

    # initialize Cloud SQL Python Connector object
    connector = Connector()

    def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
        conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
            instance_connection_name,
            "pg8000",
            user=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            db=db_name,
            ip_type=ip_type,
        )
        return conn
```

I identified four settings: instance connection name, db user, db password, and db name (code from https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions).

Also, when I look at [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/use-secret-manager),
it is implied that instance connection name, db user, and db password should be stored as a secret.

My first question is, should all these 3 be stored as separate secrets in Secrets Manager? Or should they be in a single secret in some format?
e.g. in JSON

```
{ "db_user": "my-db-user", "db_pass": "my-db-password", "instance_connection_name": "xxx" }
```

The latter would be easier to retrieve from a performance perspective when the secrets are mounted as a volume, but is less secure since the attacker needs to break access to a single secret to connect to the database rather than three.

The second question is related to the above comment: considering the overhead to connect to the SQL database, should I try to improve performance by exposing my secrets as an environment variable rather than mounting them as a volume?

The third question is what to do about the database name. It is not specified in the second article, but is it safe to store the database name in an environment variable, or should this be stored as a secret as well?

For reference, here is my current code that stores db user/pass and instance connection name in thee secrets, and mounts them as volumes in the Cloud Function:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes

connector = Connector()

def getconn():
    with open(
        "/etc/secrets1/instance-connection-name", "r", encoding="utf-8"
    ) as f:
        instance_connection_name = f.read()
    with open("/etc/secrets2/db-user", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        db_user = f.read()
    with open("/etc/secrets3/db-pass", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        db_pass = f.read()

    db_name = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")

    conn = connector.connect(
       instance_connection_name,
        "pg8000",
        user=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        db=db_name,
        ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC,
    )
    return conn


pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)


def main():
    with pool.connect() as db_conn:
        results = db_conn.execute(
            sqlalchemy.text(
                "select * from pets"
            )
        ).fetchall()

    return results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions:

1. Prefer to store the secret independently. Some can evolve quicker that other and it's easier to maintain if you have unitary secrets.
2. Env var imply to read value in memory. Reading secret in volume imply to read value in memory (there is no disk attached, it's a virtual volume in memory). It's roughly equivalent (the file option should be a little bit heavier, but it's minimize/hidden by the db connection duration)
3. Depends on you. I usually does not keep it secret.

---

What if the best solution is not to use login/password but simply the Cloud Functions identity to log into the PostgreSQL instance?

Have a look here, it's my recommended way: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authentication